# Split string value and Store in list

Tags: c#, .net, list, split

I would like to separate the string "ICMS_MG-PR-RJ-RS-SC" and need to exclude the "ICMS_" add the other values excluding the "-" to the list of string.

```
List<string> states=new List<string>();
```

The "states" should contain the values as: MG,PR,RJ,RS,SC

Comment: Not that important question to give 2 up votes

Comment: @PawanNogariya: especially because he didn't show what he has tried.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Exactly!

Answer (score 5):

Replace prefix with empty string, and split rest by `-` symbol:

```
var text = "ICMS_MG-PR-RJ-RS-SC";
var states = text.Replace("ICMS_", "").Split('-').ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var states = text.Split('_', '-').Skip(1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *lazyberezovsky*'s answer, you can also do this:

```
var input = "ICMS_MG-PR-RJ-RS-SC";
var states = input.Split('_')[1].Split('-').ToList();
```

Or this

```
var states = input.Split('_', '-').Skip(1).ToList();
```

Or this

```
var states = input.Substring(input.IndexOf('_') + 1).Split('-').ToList();
```

Note, however, unless you really need to be able to access each element by index, there's probably no need to call `ToList`. If you can settle for an `IEnumerable<string>`, you probably should.